# How to add custom StartupListener to Camel Context via Spring

Tags: spring, apache-camel

How to add custom StartupListener to Camel Context via Spring?

It sounds very easy (like adding ShutdownStrategy), but I found it very difficult.
There is nothing about it here:
http://camel.apache.org/advanced-configuration-of-camelcontext-using-spring.html

Thanks.

Comment: What do you need the StartupListener for? You can use EventNotifier which gives you callbacks when Camel has started, and it works as shown on that link you provided.

Comment: Just to send email notification about application start/stop. Stop was trivial with ShutdownStrategy, but start was not so trivial it should be. Let me try EventNotifier.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Claus and Robert. I'm answering to my question to present solution.

Indeed EventNotifier may be used instead of StartupListener, althought it would much easier just to have StartupListener working as expected :)
Anyway, the following code works like a charm:

```
public class StartStopEmailEventNotifier extends EventNotifierSupport {

    @Override
    public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
                //send start email notification
            }
            if (event instanceof CamelContextStoppingEvent) {
                //send stop email notification
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Problem with sending email: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
        if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent || event instanceof CamelContextStoppingEvent) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And Spring: `<bean id="startStopEmailEventNotifier" class="com....StartStopEmailEventNotifier"></bean>`

Answer (score 0):

On the first glance [this thread](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Callback-after-startup-from-org-apache-camel-main-Main-afterStart-td5730284.html) might be irrelevant but it's the same question as yours but in different purpose. Looks like based on pointed discussion [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6269) has been created.

Note that in pointed thread workaround can be found :).

Comment: Overriding Main is too complicated for such simple purpose I need :) I just wanted to send email notifications about application star/stop.

Comment: Since it is possible in term of stop then I'm afraid it might not be possible out of the box for start.